# Error in jquery code when using wizard-step on MVC project

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, formwizard

I am using MVC in my project and I am using a wizard-step jquery code to work with one form.

I have used wizard step for for filling a form before and it works perfect, but now when i try to use it on another view I get an error.

> Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'validate'

This is my view:

```
@using NKI.Web.ViewModels;
@model NKI.Web.ViewModels.AnswerFormViewModel

@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
    <fieldset>
     <legend></legend>
        @foreach (SelectedQuestionViewModel items in Model.AllSelectedQuestions)
        {
            <div class="wizard-step">
                <p>@items.SelectedQuestionText <span class="b">Rate:&nbsp;&nbsp; @Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.GradeNumber, items.GradesNumber, new {@class = "selectstyle"})</span></p>
                <div class="editor-field">
                @Html.TextArea("Comment", items.Comment, new {@class = "selectstyle"})
                </div>
                <br/>
                <br/>
                <br/>
            </div>
        }

        <p><input type="button" id="next-step" name="next-step" value="Next"/></p>
        <p><input type="button" id="back-step" name="back-step" value="Back"/></p>
    </fieldset>
            }
```

This is the part of my wizard-step jquery code that I get an error:

```
$("#next-step").click(function () {

    var $step = $(".wizard-step:visible"); // get current step

    var validator = $("form").validate(); // obtain validator // <--- here I get the error
    var anyError = false;
    $step.find("input").each(function () {
        if (!validator.element(this)) { // validate every input element inside this step
            anyError = true;
        }

    });

    if (anyError)
        return false; // exit if any error found
```

Anyone have any idea what the may cause the problem for this error?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: How are you including the required jQuery script files?

Comment: Thanks alot. I've forgotten a reference to a script. Thanks again